# Unity: Live video streaming

Tags: node.js, networking, unity-game-engine, websocket, server

I have 2 different Unity apps and i wish to connect them. My Aim is to stream a live video from App 2, to app 1. therefore i want app 2 to act as the server and sender, and app 1 to act as the receiver and show the video in a panel or rawimage. The 2nd app will run on IOS or android and i access the Native camera, in the finale product i wish to have whatever is visible in app 2 to be visible in app 1 image. *only the image*. What i have achieved so far:

I have actually finished all about 90% of both apps and this is the last step i need. When it comes to servers and networking i just don't have the required knowledge. Can someone tell me how can i do this? How can i stream a live video from one unity app to the other. Note: The 2nd app will be on ipad or any android phone while the 1st app will be running on a normal desktop. Regarding the networking part, should i use nodejs, websockets? Unity netoworking? What? Even if i know what to use, how shall i stream the thing. this is the first project i do that has networking and servers in it and i really don't have the experience needed for this. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: did you find your solution yet? I saw this post doing exact thing you needed.
ref:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/670270/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to stream the app it might be easier to use sockets or unity's multiplayer services and recreate the relevant assets client-side and have the server send position updates.

In terms of what to use Unity networking looks like a good choice. When I've done unity client-server stuff before I've done it with sockets and that works okay especially if you don't have too many things to keep track of.

Comment: Right but getting stuff to stream properly is complicated. If your server side only had a few objects to keep track of you could clone those assets to the client side app and send the positions over a socket connection. That also has the advantage of requiring less data passing between the server and the client.